# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetModelsInBrand(int BrandId) 
{ 
    IQueryable<Product> query = 
         from Product 
          in ObjectContext.Products.Where(p => (p.BrandId == BrandId)) 
         orderby Product.Model 
         select Product; 
        query = query.Distinct(new ProductByModelEqualityComparer()); 
        return query; 
}
```

After return query was executed, I got

> Load operation failed for query 'GetModelsInBrand'.  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method."

Can anyone help to correct it?

Comment: Please show the code where `GetModelsInBrand()` is called.

Answer (score 3):

Probably LINQ-to-entities doesn't support the code which you've written in `ProductByModelEqualityComparer`. You can call `AsEnumerable` before calling `Distinct`, this will make `Distinct` executed via linq-to-objects but it won't be `IQueryable` anymore:

```
var enumerable = query.AsEnumerable().Distinct(new ProductByModelEqualityComparer()); return query; }
```

Comment: Problem with this is that the method returns `IQueryable<T>`. Presumably he might be performing queries against the returned object and expects them to be translated into the data store's native language. If you do `AsEnumerable()` within the query you are no longer executing subsequent queries against the database.

Comment: @Chevex, I know, I wrote the same in different words

Comment: Ah, might want to make that more clear. I thought you were saying that was the intention, to make it IEnumerable.

Comment: @Chevex, I was trying to say exactly what you've said. That `AsEnumerable` will help, but it won't be linq-to-entities anymore.

Comment: I understand what you were *trying* to say now. I'm just saying that it was easily misread.